# Binding values in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I know this is a fairly simple and noobish question, but here it goes.
I have been trying to create a log-in screen with blazor.However, when I click login button, I cannot save the values.(null when I debug)

Login Page Code:

```xml
@page "/"
@attribute [StreamRendering]
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using project1.Components.Models
@using project1.Services
@inject IAtLoginPage AtLoginPage
@inject ILogedIn LogedIn
@inject NavMenuViewService ViewOption

<h1>LOGIN</h1>

<EditForm Model="@loginModel" OnValidSubmit=@ValidFormSubmitted OnInvalidSubmit=@InvalidFormSubmitted FormName="LoginForm">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.Username" class="form-control id="Username" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => loginModel.Username)" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <InputText id="password" @bind-Value="loginModel.Password" type="password" class="form-control" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => loginModel.Password)" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    protected LoginModel loginModel;
    string LastSubmitResult;


    public void LoginCheck()
    {
        string dummyUser = "admin";
        string dummyPass = "1234";
        Console.WriteLine("Login Check");
        if ((loginModel.Username != null && loginModel.Password != null) && (dummyUser == loginModel.Username && dummyPass == loginModel.Password))
        {
            LogedIn.logInChecker = true;
        }
    }


    void ValidFormSubmitted(EditContext editContext)
    {
        LastSubmitResult = "OnValidSubmit was executed";
        LoginCheck();
    }

    void InvalidFormSubmitted(EditContext editContext)
    {
        LastSubmitResult = "OnInvalidSubmit was executed";
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        loginModel  = new LoginModel();
    }
}
```

My Model

```cs
namespace project1.Components.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        
        public string? Username { get; set; }
        public string? Password { get; set; }

        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

I click login button, I cannot save the values.(null when I debug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depend on interactivity mode you have. Question is tagged blazor-wasm, but you have the [StreamRendering] attribute, which implies the the server side rendering (SSR).

In case of SSR, you have to use `SupplyParameterFromForm` and initialize the model only when null. As is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0). Also your model has to be a property.

```cs
 [SupplyParameterFromForm]
 public LoginModel loginModel {get;set};

 protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        loginModel??=new();
    }
```